# C# Json to custom class

Tags: c#, json

I have json:

```
[
     {
        "Name" : "SHA of timestamp",
        "ProjectURL" : "URL to Proj",
        "AccountIdentifier" : "Account Identifier",
        "Repositories":
        {
            "GitLink1": 
            {
                "Login" : "login1",
                "Password"  : "pas1"
            },
            "GitLink2": 
            {
                "Login" : "login2",
                "Password"  : "pas2"
            },  
            
            ...
            
            "GitLink999":
            {
                "Login" : "login999",
                "Password" : "pass999"
            }
        }
    },
    
    ...
    
    {
        Same entry
    }
]
```

I need to fill it in IEnumerable of my created classes

```
public class Git
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Repositories
{
    public Git git { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigEntry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProjectURL { get; set; }
    public string AccountIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Repositories Repositories { get; set; }
}
```

Using

```
IEnumerable<ConfigurationEntry> config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ConfigurationEntry>>(CONFIGJSON);
```

Where CONFIGJSON contains frst json file.

Gives me this data of ConfigEntry class :

> Name : "filled with some data"
>
> ProjectURL : same
>
> AccountIdentifier : same
>
> Repositories : NULL

How i can fill Repositories field with all data i have in config JSON?

Is there any ideas.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you probably shouldn't have a `Repositories` class - instead, change your `ConfigEntry.Repositories` property to:

```
public Dictionary<string, Git> Repositories { get; set; }
```

Then you'll get a dictionary where the key of "GetLink1" has a value with Login of "login1" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your class definitions aren't quite right.

Your "repositories" class only contains a single Git, but needs to be a Dictionary.

I think if you use this you will be close:

```
public class Git
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
public class ConfigEntry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProjectURL { get; set; }
    public string AccountIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,Git> Repositories { get; set; }
}
```

you may also need a non-generic IEnumerable, so it knows which objects to actually create:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ConfigurationEntry>>(CONFIGJSON);
```